# How to count all check checkbox from selected row using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I would have a page where table with selected rows are generated with single checkbox for each cell using JQuery. Table columns are fixed as for 12 months.

As the rows are generated based on dropdown. Then the no of rows generated would get values in another dropdown too.

I want to get the counts of all checked checkbox from the row number as get selected from another dropdown on button click using JQuery.
Code is below

**HTML:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CheckBox.aspx.cs" Inherits="PracticeWebApp.CheckBox" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="CSS/assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="CSS/assets/dist/css/customstyl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="CSS/assets/dist/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20130526/json2.min.js"></script>

    <script src="JS/CheckBox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <%--<input type="button" id="btnGenerate" value="Generate Table" />&nbsp;--%>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="hidden" id="msghf" />
                Generate Table of Rows &nbsp;<select id="DropDownListcols" class="form-control-sm">
                    <option value="0">SELECT</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                </select>
                &nbsp;
            <input type="submit" id="submitbutton" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="display:none;" />
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                &nbsp; Get Selected Checkbox of Row No &nbsp;<select id="ddlselectrow" class="form-control-sm">
                     
                </select>&nbsp;
                <input type="submit" id="submitbuttongetchecked" value="View" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div id="xmldisplay">
                        </div>
                        <div id="dvTable">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CheckBox.js:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#DropDownListcols").change(function () {
        //debugger;
        //Get the count of columns.
        var options = null;
        var totalrows = $(this).val();
        options += '<option value="0">SELECT</option>';
        for (var a = 1; a <= totalrows; a++) {
            options += '<option value="' + a + '">' + a + '</option>';
        }
        $('#ddlselectrow').append(options);

        var columnCount = 12;
        //Create a HTML Table element.
        var table = '<table class="table table-bordered" id="Mastertable">';
        table += '<thead class="thead-dark freeze">';
        for (var mon = 1; mon <= 12; mon++) {
            table += '<th>' + toMonthName(mon) + '</th>';
        }
        
        //Create table header according to number of columns
         
        table += '</thead>';
        table += '<tbody>';
        for (var j = 0; j < totalrows; j++) {
            table += '<tr id="rowid_' + (j + 1) + '">';
            for (var z = 0; z < columnCount; z++) {
                table += GetRowswithCheckBoxes(toMonthName(z+1), (z + 1).toString(), (j + 1).toString());
            }
            table += '</tr>';
        }
        table += '</tbody>';
        table += '</table>';

        $("#dvTable").html("");
        $("#dvTable").html(table);

        //BindCheckedCheckbox();

    });

    //$("#submitbutton").click(function (e) {
    //    e.preventDefault();
    //    //alert('Hello');
    //    SaveXMLDatatoDatabase();
    //});
});

function toMonthName(monthNumber) {
    const date = new Date();
    date.setMonth(monthNumber - 1);

    return date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
        month: 'short',
    });
}

function GetRowswithCheckBoxes(namevar, cols, rows) {
    var a = '<td><input type="checkbox" value="chk' + namevar + '" id="chk' + namevar + '_Col' + cols + '_Row' + rows + '"/></td>'
    return a;
}

$(function () {
    $("#submitbuttongetchecked").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        debugger;
        var checkboxes;
        var rowcheckfor = $('#ddlselectrow').val();
        var id = $("#Mastertable #rowid_" + rowcheckfor);
        $(id).each(function () {
            checkboxes = $(":checkbox:checked").length;
            
            //return false;
        });
        alert("Row No : " + rowcheckfor + ", Checked : " + checkboxes);
    })
});
```

As you see the function mentioned in above code:

```
$(function () {
        $("#submitbuttongetchecked").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            debugger;
            var checkboxes;
            var rowcheckfor = $('#ddlselectrow').val();
            var id = $("#Mastertable #rowid_" + rowcheckfor);
            $(id).each(function () {
                checkboxes = $(":checkbox:checked").length;
                
                //return false;
            });
            alert("Row No : " + rowcheckfor + ", Checked : " + checkboxes);
        })
    });
```

It is defined to check all the checkboxes in the selected row. But it iterating through all the rows. How should I get the count of checked checkboxes in row selected from the Dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine....

but you missed this

```
checkboxes =  $(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length;
```

change this your code ., it works

```
$(function () {
    $("#submitbuttongetchecked").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       
        var checkboxes;
        var rowcheckfor = $('#ddlselectrow').val();
        var id = $("#Mastertable #rowid_" + rowcheckfor);
       // alert(rowcheckfor);
        $(id).each(function () {
        // debugger;
            checkboxes =  $(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length;
            
            //return false;
        });
        alert("Row No : " + rowcheckfor + ", Checked : " + checkboxes);
    })
});
```

This will all the checkboxes in the form

```
 checkboxes = $(":checkbox:checked").length;
```

Comment: I do not want to count all the checkboxes, that I am getting already. I just want that if I would select 1 from dropdown `#ddlselectrow`, then should iterate through first row  and count all the checked checkboxes from first row only. And If select the value 2 from `#ddlselectrow` then should iterate through second row and count all checked checkboxes from second row only and so on.

Comment: yeah that's what the first line will do. checkboxes =  $(this).find(':checkbox:checked').length; ., use and check it